# C++-CLI/C# and passing unicode

Tags: c#, .net, visual-c++, unicode, c++-cli

I'm currently writing a program in C++ which makes use of an API in C#. I need to pass this C# package a unicode symbol (which it will then draw).

The documentation, unfortunately, doesn't account for managed code. The C# example it gives is just:

```
String text = "\u2197\u2300\u21A7";
```

But when I try to do this in the C++:

```
String^ convertedText= gcnew String("\u2313");
```

I get the error:

```
"Character represented by universal-character-name "\u2313" cannot be represent in the current code page (1252)"
```

I'm not going quite sure how to go about fixing this. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Does making it a wide-character string literal (`L"\u2313"`) work?

Comment: Hmm, it's odd. It does seem to work, kind of. For 2313 it displays a square, which is something, I guess, but not what it should be. For 2300 it doesn't display anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++/CLI is still C++ so `"this string"` is not Unicode (which is default in C#). Just add `L` prefix like this:

```
String^ convertedText = gcnew String(L"\u2313");
```

Or simply:

```
String^ convertedText = L"\u2313";
```

See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6aw8xdf2.aspx) on MSDN for C++ reference and [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664669%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for C# reference. In your case these representations are equivalent to your original C# string `"\u2197\u2300\u21A7`:

```
L"\u2197\u2300\u21A7"
L"\x2197\x2300\x21A7"
L"↗⌀↧"
```

`\u` can be used to specify Unicode surrogates and modifiers, for simple characters you can use `\x` too.

Comment: Hmm, if I do it using the capital U it gives me an error, saying that it's "an incorrectly formed universal character name" (it's recognising that's it's unicode though, so that's progress!).

Comment: Oh, it's 2300 that I'm trying to use actually, not that it'll really make a difference.

Comment: @Incredidave sorry, `\U` is for UTF-16 and `\u` is for UTF-8.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that in the article you linked.

Comment: Moreover if you don't have to specify Unicode surrogates just use L"" with \x.

Comment: What do you mean? Like L"\x2300"? I have to feed the string I get into a function from the C# API that then renders it, so I think it has to be in unicode.

Comment: @Incredidave it'll be unicode because of `L`. Then you can set content directly with characters you need (saving file as UTF-8) or using `\u` (mostly for unicode surrogates and modifiers) or more easily with `\x` if you just need a non ANSI character. `L"\u2197\u2300\u21A7"` in C++ is exactly equivalent to or `L"\x2197\x2300\x21A7"` `L"↗⌀↧"` or your original C# `"\u2197\u2300\u21A7"` string.

Comment: Hmm, okay, that's helpful, thanks. I think it might be working now, in that the correct character is being used. Unfortunately it's still not displaying, but I suspect that might be a problem with the implementation using the API for rendering it. I'll mark your answer correct anyway.

Comment: @Incredidave try how it works in a simple WinForms application. You should get same string from C# and C++ (just avoid Console!!!).